# JBoss AMQ / ActiveMQ Artemis: Pre-configure Durable Subscribers

Tags: activemq-artemis, amq, durable-subscription

I have a Red Hat AMQ (which is based on ActiveMQ Artemis) broker and I would like to make use of durable subscription (or equivalent) feature, so that I will have multiple OpenWire JMS subscribers subscribing to the events of our application which will be delivered to them reliably.

I would like to pre-configure subscribers, so to save me trouble in initial application startup. I want to avoid the case for initial application start up where the main application starts running and publishing events before our durable subscribers perform their initial subscription.

I also wants to avoid explicitly ordering start up sequence of my processes.

Is there any way I can pre-configure durable subscribers?  In ordinary ActiveMQ (not Artemis), there is feature like Virtual Topics which (kind of) solve the problem.

What is the preferred solution for ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: What kind of client are you using?

Comment: Just wonder how this is related to the question?

Comment: Because the name of the queue created for a "durable subscription" may be different depending on which client is being used.  Also, did you read the [Artemis documentation on this](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/address-model.html#advanced-address-configuration)?

Comment: FYI - the [STOMP chapter in the Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/stomp.html#durable-subscriptions) also discusses this.

Comment: I am going to use it with JMS (ah... I should have mentioned it in the question).  Lemme keep STOMP in my broker config and try if this works, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your JMS client? Will you be using the core protocol, OpenWire, or AMQP? Artemis supports JMS implementations using each of those protocols.

Comment: Seems our clients are using Openwire.  I was originally thinking of enabling STOMP (though not used) with the configuration you mentioned should cause the durable subscription be created and is available for other protocols.  May I know if it may work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pre-configure durable subscriptions since the OpenWire implementation creates the queue used for the durable subscription in a deterministic way (i.e. using the format of `client-id`.`subscription-name`). For example, if you wanted to configure a durable subscription on the address `myAddress` with a client-id of `myclientid` and a subscription name of `mysubscription` then configure the durable subscription:

```
<addresses>
   <address name="myAddress">
       <multicast>
        <queue name="myclientid.mysubscription"/>
      </multicast>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It works as expected.  Sorry for the belated acceptance as I didn't have chance to test that out till now  :)